# How can I add a success function?

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a success and fail function but how can I do it? I have this code below:

```
    class ={};

    class.hey = function(values)
    {
      document.getElementById(values.id).innerHTML = values.Val ;

    return class;
    }



    class.hey({
    id:"target",
    Val: "hello world",//this wil work and will display that value in the span tag
    })

<span id="target"></span>//here will appear the value passed before
```

How could I add a function that tells me if everything was ok or wrong? Ive been trying but i cannot solve this
Example of how id like that works

```
    class ={};

    class.hey = function(values)
    {
      document.getElementById(values.id).innerHTML = values.Val ;

    return class;
    }



    class.hey({
    id:"objetive",//the element does not exist
    Val: "hello world",//this wil work and will display that value in the span tag
    success:function(msg)
        {
 alert("ok!")

},

     error:function(msg){
      alert("wrong");
   }
    })

<span id="target"></span>//here will appear the value passed before
```

Comment: Are you trying to do jQuery without jQuery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not something that is automatic to JavaScript at all, but you can do it:

```
class.hey = function (value) {
    var value = document.getElementById(values.id);
    if (!value) {
        value.error(values.id + " is not an element")
        return false;
    }
    value.innerHTML = values.val;
    value.success("okay!");
}
```